# Does talking consistently without pauses contribute to jitter in VoIP? Can end-user behaviour mitigate low bandwidth?

Tags: networking, audio, voip

I have developed a hunch while using Skype/Zoom/Hangouts etc that, when bandwidth is constrained, talking for long periods without pausing can cause the audio to be garbled at the other end.

To be clear, my hypothesis is that there's a bandwidth range in which talking with frequent pauses *will not* cause garbling, while talking with no pauses *will*. I have no idea whether that's true or not.

Behind this question is the hope that there are a few tips we could give bandwidth-impaired users that would give a better VoIP experience. For example, I've noticed that sudden inflections of speech or a sudden increase in volume can distort audio. I have assumed that this has something to do with compression.

Am I on the right track with this line of reasoning? Is there any research into how user behavior affects VoIP? Is this the right community to ask this question?

Comment: What do you define as low bandwidth? What speeds do you receive up/down? What's the router make/model?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart if it's a stupid question it's a stupid question. It doesn't feel like a stupid question to me, but I'm happy to be told otherwise. I think I'm actually asking a question about the software, not the hardware - how the software handles tradeoffs when tradeoffs have to be made. I would have thought that one could hold the variables you mention constant, or at least provide examples where my hypothesis does hold true. If that's not the case, I apologise for asking stupid questions, although I don't promise to stop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this can be definitively answered as it depends on the networks in question, however I have some experience and can provide comments and observations that may be useful.

VOIP typically uses a fairly standard amount of bandwidth, and its not a lot (the amount depends on a number of things, but particularly the codec used - anywhere between 6kbit and 80kbit)

Jitter has a specific meaning - it is the difference between the highest and lowest "ping" time - the lower the jitter, the better.   Jitter in-and-of-itself will not cause garbling, but it could cause delays or lost speach depending on how VOIP is configured.

What may be happening is that service providers you are going through have constrained bandwidth, and they are allowing a priority amount (ie burst).  It is possible that when you are talking you are exceeding the nominal bandwidth, but not the burst bandwidth - and when you pause you are not using bandwdith, so you are bringing your average usage down below the average bandwidth.   If you don't stop talking you are exceeding this and they will start dropping packets to slow the connection down.

**Its worth considering that there is a relationship between buffer sizes, jitter and packet loss.  Depending on the traffic management algorithm used this could cause the symptoms you are seeing - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat**   IF you are experiencing bufferbloat, then yes, your are on the right track.

The thing is that a good network should not experience bufferbloat, even if its congested.   There are multiple strategies used by competent providers to handle this.